# Php, MySql join 3 tables ,and calculate SUM

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 3 tables project, times and expense. I want to join all 3 of them and calculate sum as well as retrieve all the matching records.

Here are my tables:

```
projects:
id      name
=====================
1       First Project
2       Second Project

times:
id      project_id  hours       billed
===================================================
1       1           2.0         1
2       1           3.0         0
3       2           4.30        0

expense:
id      project_id  amount         billed
==================================================
1       1           120.00         0
2       2           35.00          1
3       2           55.00          0
4       2           45.00          0
```

and here is my query:

```
  SELECT 
    SUM(t.hours) as total_hours,
    SUM(e.amount) as total_amount,
    p.name
  FROM
    `projects` AS p 
    LEFT JOIN `expense` AS e 
      ON e.project_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN `times` AS t 
      ON t.project_id = p.id 
  WHERE t.billed = 0
  AND e.billed = 0
  GROUP BY p.id;
```

But for some reason I cant make it to work, I end up with no records.

The result should look something like:

```
Name            Total Hours     Total Expense
==============================================
First Project   3.00             120.00
----------------------------------------------
Second Project  7.30             100.00
----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have the table aliases the wrong way around:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(e.hours) as total_hours,
    SUM(t.amount) as total_amount,
    p.name
  FROM
    `projects` AS p 
    LEFT JOIN `expense` e 
      ON e.project_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN `times` t 
      ON t.project_id = p.id 
  WHERE t.billed = 0
  AND e.billed = 0
  GROUP BY p.id;
```

Works as expected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48bfd1/3

Comment: These are really INNER JOINs, as EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS would demonstrate.

Comment: @colburton The aliases are actually correct, it was a typo with table names. I have updated  my post.